# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes when using java8 parallelStream()

Tags: java, multithreading, encryption, thread-safety, rsa

My code:

`blotterlist.parallelStream().filter(p -> p.size() > 0).forEach(p -> decrypt(p));`

```
private void decrypt(List<BlotterView> blotter) {
    for (BlotterView blotterView : blotter) {
        try {
            String s = crypto.encrypt(blotterView.getCreditCardNumber());
            crypto.decrypt(s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code throws exception. 
But instead of using the parallelStream, when I used the normal for loop it didn't throw exception.

Note. The Crypto is an implementation of RSA algo and methods are not Syncronized.

Comment: RSA will not en/decrypt data bigger than it's key size. I guess you are using a key size of 2048 bit since you hit the 256 byte limit.

Comment: You are correct  Pedersen. But the Exception was not thrown when I used  normal for loop.  Exception is thrown only when I used parallelStream for the same list. (I have edited my question also)

Comment: Doesn't affect your actual problem, but as a style suggestion, consider using `.filter(p -> !p.isEmpty())` instead of `.filter(p -> p.size() > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You say: "Note. The Crypto is an implementation of RSA algo and methods are not Syncronized."

I don't see the `crypto` object being passed into your `decrypt()` method, which strongly indicates that `crypto` is some single object being shared by all calls to `decrypt()`.

If that's the case, the fact that the `crypto`'s methods are not synchronized is probably what's causing the problem.  When you use `parallelStream()` you are setting up a situation where multiple threads are allowed to be used to process the stream.  That means that `decrypt()` can be called simultaneously from multiple threads.  And if those multiple, simultaneous invocations of `decrypt()` are indeed sharing a single, unsynchronized `crypto` object, then you are very likely going to have problems since you'll be a using a thread-unsafe object from multiple threads.

By contrast, when you just use `stream()` all the processing is happening in a single thread, so you most likely won't have any problems.

Here's an example of how a problem *could* happen (I'm not claiming this is the specific thing going on):

If `crypto` is not thread safe then `crypto.decrypt()` could do something like putting data in a per-object buffer as it processes it. But then you call `crypto.decrypt()` again from another thread while the first one is still processing. That overwrites the buffer and basically pulls the rug out from under the first call to `crypto.decrypt()`, leading to errors. Not saying that's literally what's happening but it's highly likely something akin to that.

Comment: Yes. But I dont get the point how the strings are muted in between. Anyway using stream() wont speed up the processing.

Comment: Of course it won't.  But you don't have a choice.  You (likely) either need to have the decrypts run in a single thread, or have `decrypt()` create/obtain an instance of `crypto` that isn't shared with another thread, or make the `crypto` implementation be thread-safe.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "how the strings are muted in between".  Anyways, if `crypto` is not thread safe then `crypto.decrypt()` could do something like putting data in a buffer as it processes it.  But then you call `crypto.decrypt()` again while the first one is still processing.  That overwrites the buffer and basically "pulls the rug out from under" the first call to `crypto.decrypt()`, leading to errors. Not saying that's literally what's happening but it's highly likely something akin to that.